# Referencing integers in a vector

Tags: rust, vector, borrow-checker

I am learning rust at the moment and can't seem to understand the point of using `&` in this example from the book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch08-01-vectors.html#reading-elements-of-vectors

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let third: &i32 = &v[2];
```

Aren't these 2 code examples equivalent?

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let third: i32 = v[2];
```

I am particularly confused about the `&i32`. Is the point, that I share the same pointer to `i32` at `index 2`? Is that even possible, because I thought simple values will always be copied and therefore you can't reference a simple value from 2 places.

Super grateful if someone could clear this up for me.

Comment: You can have many pointers for a single value (primitive or not) as long as the ref is inmutable and with equal of shorter lifetime.

Comment: This is not like e.g. Java when primitives are always copied, in Rust all values can have references to.

Comment: @Peterrabbit Thanks, that makes sense. Just so I understand correctly:

In the first example, `third` and `v[2]` would point to the same chunk on the stack and in the second example, `third` and `v[2]` would point (own) two different chunks on the stack?

Comment: Yes exactely, in the first you get the address in memory of `v[2]`, so the `third` variable is a pointer to the value at `v[2]`, and in the second example `third` is just a copy of the value at `v[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that even possible, because I thought simple values will always be copied and therefore you can't reference a simple value from 2 places.

The rule is not that “simple values” (more precisely, values implementing the `Copy` trait) are copied rather than referenced. Rather, it is that they are copied rather than *moved*. The copy happens at the point `let third: i32 = v[2];` and if you used a non-`Copy` type then it would be an error:

```rust
let v = vec![vec![1, 2], vec![3, 4], vec![5, 6]];

// error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Vec<i32>>`
let third: Vec<i32> = v[2];
```

(If you want to review these concepts, see [§4.1 What is Ownership?](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) which talks about moves, copies, and `Copy`.)

Rust *allows* you to take a reference to any type. Sometimes this is pointless; for example an `&i32` is no more useful than an `i32`, but you're still allowed to create it. (But an `&mut i32` might be useful for modifying the `i32` in-place.)

So, the two examples are both allowed. In a practical program working on `i32`s (and not some other non-`Copy` type), you will almost always write the second one — but using a `Copy` type allows *demonstrating the relationship*.